# Django 1.9 date object import from csv

Tags: python, django, csv

The date from my csv is in the format mm/dd/yyyy

I edited settings.py to include:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y'] 
    # '2006-10-25', '10/25/2006', '10/25/06'
```

When assigning the csv row to the db model, I get this error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

This is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import csv
import django
from datetime import date as django_date

sys.path.append("/home/nerdbox2/django_/logbook/")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "logbook.settings"
django.setup()

from flights.models import Flight

f = Flight()

reader = csv.reader(open('path to file'))


for row in reader: #reads row from csv


f.date = django_date(row[0])
f.aircraft = row[1]
f.save()
```

If I do something like: `f.date = django_date(int(row[0]))`

I get: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'date'`

I think the problem is that since the input format is `yyyy/mm/dd` that the `'/'` character can't be turned into an `int()` but how to I make the string into a date object that Django will accept?

Comment: try using datetime lib, it works wonders

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with django when you want to parse an individual date string. You need to use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to convert datetime string into datetime objects:

```
import datetime
f.date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016/01/01', '%Y/%m/%d').date()
```

In your case it would be:

```
import datetime
f.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y/%m/%d').date()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I tried: 
    f.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y').date()

Since my date format is 3/3/2016. I saw that %m and %d are zero padded but I still get 

    ValueError: time data 'date' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'

I also removed the code from Django settings.py since it doesn't help.

Comment: The padding zeros shouldn't matter. I couldn't help you because I don't have your data. You should try each date individually and see if any row is having wrong data. Maybe you have `date` first then `month` because month 28 doesn't make sense. Or you could print each `row[0]` and see which data gives you problem.

Comment: 8/1/2015
    8/2/2015
    8/3/2015
    8/8/2015
    8/9/2015
    8/10/2015
    8/13/2015
    8/14/2015
    8/15/2015
    8/16/2015
    8/21/2015
    8/22/2015
    8/23/2015
    9/3/2015
    9/4/2015
    9/5/2015
    9/6/2015
    9/16/2015
    9/23/2015
    9/27/2015
    9/28/2015
    9/29/2015
    9/30/2015
    10/1/2015  

Ugh, formatting... But this is a year's worth of data. I'd greatly appreciate another look!

Comment: I don't understand your example. Are you saying these dates all give you the same error or they are the data you currently have? Have you tried in django shell to test `strptime`? There are so many things you can do to test this. Do all rows give you the same error?

Comment: Well, it looks like I wasn't taking into account that the first record of row is the table header. Your example works excellent! Thank you very much.

Comment: Yea I figured there's definitely something going on. Glad that it works.